# Trouble sorting merged cells in excel. Cant sort by column.

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, merge

So I am currently trying to sort by column in my excel table but it says I cannot because "to do this, all merged cells must be the same size".

I have a table that has merged cells in column A,B,C,D,and H.
Columns E, F, G are all normal and are not merged. I am trying to SORT these by column C then by Column A. I need help figuring this out. How can I sort this table if it includes merged cells.

I need all of the values to stay with each other and just sort like you normally should be able to.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: If you mean, for example, that you have rows 1, 2, and 3 for column C merged then you would simply have to unmerge them and sort. But if you do that, the value will be in only one cell and not the other ones it was merged with. I would think that would be undesirable since the merged rows should be kept with every unmerged row in adjacent columns. All I can think of is to unmerge, copy the cell to the blank cells after unmerging, and then sort.

Comment: I feel like there should be a macro that can solve this issue

Comment: There certainly is but it would require a fair amount of coding. Take a shot at it and post your code. People will help when they see what you've tried.

Comment: dont really have much of a coding background

Comment: Table operations require data shaped like a *table*. Merged cells look pretty, but thwart that. Your only solution is to unmerge and shape your data in a data-friendly way, *then* format it in an eye-friendly way. Or should you be using a pivot table instead?

Comment: It would mess with the functionality of the table and the look. Is there no way to do this without unmerging my cells?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the columns?  Or the rows in the column?  Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Don't merge cells!!  As you are finding out, that will quickly become the bane of your existence.